# Keeping moment.js out of my Angular build output

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs, typescript-typings

I'm developing an Angular Spa (using Angular CLI) and I would like to have `moment.js` included in the page as an external script:

```
    <script src="/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
```

This, because I want to move the loading of only the relevant locales to the server side, and having moment.js out of the build is the first step.

So, I need to make the rest of the build to work using this import mechanism, ideally keeping Moment.js typings somewhat working. Something like:

```
declare const moment: moment.MomentType;
// or something like
interface Window {
  moment: moment.MomentType
}
```

This syntax (or any variation of it I can come up) keeps me getting errors along the lines of `Cannot find namespace 'moment'`.

I already tried to remove every `import { moment } from 'moment';` around, I tried variations of `declare const moment: any;`, but they don't give me type safety, and I can't find a way to import `moment.d.ts`, either via `tsconfig` `"files"` property or in the project's `tsconfig.app.json` `"include"` property.

Is there a way to make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I found a solution, after all.

The solution is twofold:

1. Insert in the page a `script` tag for moment, and a tag for the appropriate locale. I do this in my server-generated MVC view.
   The same two tags are included in the `index.html` page I use for Angular development with `ng serve`.
   This provides a `moment` object **inside the global `window`**.

```html
    <script src="/assets/lib/moment/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/lib/moment/locale/it.js"></script>
```

2. In Angular dev mode, I removed EVERY single `import moment from 'moment';` and `import * as moment from 'moment';` or variations of it.
   Instead, I use a local `const moment = window['moment'];`.
   This would not give me any type safety, but I can leverage the new `import` syntax of Typescript ([here](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/dynamic-import-expressions-in-typescript) for a nice presentation and [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import) for the reference) to access the *type* of the `moment` module:

```js
// just importing the module for the type
// will not add the module to the build output
export const moment: typeof import('moment') = window['moment'];
type Moment = import('moment').Moment;
type LongDateFormatSpec = import('moment').LongDateFormatSpec;
type DurationInputObject = import('moment').DurationInputObject;
type Locale = import('moment').Locale;
```

And, voilà, we just shaved ~300 KB from the build and can still write type safe code.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a separate build file for moment js like this

*angular.json*

```js
"scripts": [
  {
    "inject": true,
    "bundleName": "moment-build",
    "input": "node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js"
  }
]
```

> `inject :true` this add a script element for `moment-build.js` in `index.html`

as example this build by import the moment directly in main component

[image: angular-build-result]

and this the build result when I create a separate build file `moment-build.js`

[image: final-build-result]

Comment: Thanks @malbarmavi for the input. However, this doesn't explain how to make use of moment in my TypeScript files: I can just access it as window['moment'] or similar "hacks", but how can I tell TypeScript/Angular that window.moment is the main moment object?

Comment: as moment available globally  `import { Moment } from 'moment'; declare const moment: Moment;` then you can access it